depthimage_to_laserscan does not work with OAK-D PRO on Humble/Jazzy
I did ros2 launch depthai_examples stereo_inertial_node.launch.py and  ros2 run depthimage_to_laserscan depthimage_to_laserscan_node --ros-args --remap depth:=/stereo/depth --remap scan:=/scan to convert to laserscan. It is not publishing anything on /scan though while it is publishing on /stereo/depth. What could be the cause of this? I tried on Humble and Jazzy but both don't work, also the depthimage_to_laserscan does not print anything after launching.
